# How to iterate simultaneously two arrays and put the elements in a specific place in a function (in Mathematica)?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to make some pie plots and each one will have different data and different title.

```
columnofdata = {"Diagnóstico_de_demência", "Transtornos_psiquiátricos", 
   "Cadeirante", "Acamado", "Sequelas_neurológicas"};

titles = {"Diagnóstico de Demência", "Transtornos_psiquiátricos", 
   "Cadeirante", "Acamado", "Sequelas Neurológicas"};

PieChart[Counts[data[All, #1]],
  PlotLabel -> Style[#2, 15]]
```

I want to get the first element of *columnofdata* array and put in the position where is *#1*, then the first element of the array *titles* and put it where is the *#2*.

Then get the second element of both arrays and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
PieChart[Counts[data[All, First@#]], PlotLabel -> Style[Last@#, 15]] & /@ 
 Transpose[{columnofdata, titles}]
```